# Marriage non catholic and divorced

Tags: catholicism, marriage

I am a baptized Christian (church of England). I was married in a civil ceremony (Registry office in the UK) 15 years ago but divorced 10 years ago. My ex wife was never baptized.

My fiancee is Catholic and never married. 
We are planning on marrying next year in a Catholic ceremony in the USA.

Do I need to get the former marriage annulled by the Catholic church, or was it never valid in the first place?

Comment: An annulation is only possible **if** the marriage has never been valid. However as far as I know the Catholic Church normally sees marriages in civil ceremonys as invalid. I have also heard about another rule (I'm not sure): Divorcement and a second marriage is said to be allowed if a Christian gets divorced from a non-Christian because of religious problems in the marriage and wants to marry a Christian...

Comment: Hi Joe!  I hope these linked duplicates help.  If you don't think they address your question, please specify why.  Note that we can't give you particular advice on what to do, but we can tell you what the Catholic Church teaches.